# delay for not running other lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this code i want to when div with .ch1 class changed background to answer_box_small_orange.png other bottom js lines code don't run and no ajax request sends until 3 seconds and i used

```
window.setTimeout(function () {}, 3000)
```

but it doesnt work correctly

here first of all i request and get data and it is ok

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'http://207.154.251.233:8039/app.php/question/get',
    data:JSON.stringify({apikey:'jwebdpqodp9fgkwjebfkdpqihdqlwkndqp'}),
    success:(function (response) {
        var x = response;
        $("#question").text(x.result.question);
        $(".op1").text(x.result.options["1"]);
    })
});
```

i inserted ajax code and some other codes in function because i want to run it every 60 seconds

```
function myInterval () {
    $(".ch1").css('background-image','url(image/answer_box_small.png)');
    var clock;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 60, {
            clockFace: 'Counter',
            autoStart: true,
            countdown: true,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    $('#loading').fadeIn('5000');
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url:'http://79.175.166.98/',
                        data:JSON.stringify({apikey:'jwebdpqodp9fgkwjebfkdpqihdqlwkndqp'}),
                        success:(function (response) {
                            $('#loading').fadeOut('slow');
                            var x = response;
                            $("#question").text(x.result.question);
                            $(".op1").text(x.result.options["1"]);
                            var answer = x.result.answer;
                            if(answer == 1){
                                $(".ch1").css('background-image','url(image/answer_box_small_orange.png)');
                            }
                           window.setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);
                        })
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
myInterval();
window.setInterval(function(){
    myInterval();
}, 60000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't block the script, it just schedules the function to run later.

Comment: @Barmar how can i block script for example 3 seconds.im confused . i googled it and nothing useful found

Comment: you didn't find anything because it's almost always wrong for Javascript to block the page. There's nothing in Javascript to do this.

Comment: You could display a model dialog with no close button, and use `setTimeout` to remove it.

Comment: This question is too confusing. Can you clarify it a little more? You want to run an ajax call every 6/3 seconds, or block the script from running for 6/3 seconds?

Comment: @JustinJmnz i want to run function every 60 second and send ajax every 60 second. and my problem is when ajax in function sent and the background of div with .ch class changed it waits for 3 seconds and then run continuance of script and then send next ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you told me, my interpretation is that you have a `setTimeout()` function and a `setInterval()` function. The `setTimeout()` runs at the beginning and will wait for 3 seconds. Then call an `ajax` function to create new requests every 6 seconds. Your problem seems to be that your first `setTimeout()` is re-run after you create your first `AJAX` request, but you want it to stop.

Taken from [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

> setTimeout Return Value: A Number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearTimeout() method to cancel the timer.

Knowing this, we can essentially cancel a `setTimout()` function. In your case, the first `setTimeout()`.

Consider this,

```
var firstIntervalID = setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax() {
    // First AJAX ran after three seconds.
    }
}, 3000);

clearTimeout(firstIntervalID);

// Your code resumes to set an interval every 60 seconds without having to worry about the three seconds set before
myInterval();
var secondIntervalID = setInterval(function(){
    myInterval();
}, 60000);
```

Essentially, you cancel the `setTimeout()` when you don't need it anymore. Your application for it can be different than what I wrote, but the main idea is the same. Cancel/Clear the `setTimeout()` with the `ID` that is returned on `setTimeout()` with `clearTimeout()`.